# Find a deterministic finite automaton for the regular paperfolding sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science, automata

The regular paperfolding sequence is defined for $n \geq 0 $ per the following rules. $\epsilon_{2n} = (-1)^n$ and $\epsilon_{2n+1} = \epsilon_n$. How would I draw a deterministic finite automaton diagram for a DFA which accepts n if and only if $\epsilon_n = 1$?

I've tried reading input both from left to right, and from right to left, but I can't think of a good way to handle the state transitions. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take $n$ as the input of your automaton, and accept $n$ iff $\epsilon_n = 1$, I think the keyword you're looking for is *[automatic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence)*.

Since the paper-folding sequence is an example a such a ($2-$)automatic sequence, you can indeed find an automaton which tells you what is $\epsilon_n$ when you feed it the binary representation of $n$.

This automaton is depicted [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_de_pliage_de_papier#Automate) (in french, sorry), and more about this can be found in the link of [the OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A014577) (J.-P. Allouche and J. Shallit, Automatic Sequences, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2003, pp. 155, 182. seems to be particularity indicated)